# Custom taxonomy is crashing Gutenberg

Tags: taxonomy, block-editor

I have a custom taxonomy, "Type" and I have it registered to my custom post type "Resource." But if I enable "show_in_rest" I get a JS error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transientEdits' of undefined
```

and Gutenberg doesn't load up.

Here's my tax:

```
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels, 
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'type', array( 'resource' ), $args );
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the taxonomy name fixes. I'll wager the guess that having it called 'type' was conflicting with the Gutenberg js.

```
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'resource-type', array( 'resource' ), $args );
```

Comment: See [Reserved Terms in The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms)